# I need to change bat - script to make it possible to use from JS in one line

Tags: javascript, batch-file, cmd

I am writing photoshop script. I need to launch exiftool to change some exif tags. 
Fot doing this I am use app.system(), that call cmd command to system:

```
app.system("start cmd /k for /f \"usebackq delims=:\" %i in (`" + exiftoolLocation + " -s \"" + name1+docName[1]+'-2'+'.jpg' + "\"` ) do ( " echo %i ^| find /i \"a\" ");
```

that prints all tag keys contains 'a'. Now, if I want to remove that tags, I have to apply "exiftool -tagName= fileName". How can I do this?

Limitation: I can't write additional script for that, I need do everything from JS.

There is bat-script, which doing what I want:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=:" %%k in (`exiftool -s "1.jpg" ^| find /i "a"`) do (
       exiftool -"%%k"= "1.jpg")
```

But

```
app.system("start cmd /k for /f \"usebackq delims=:\" %i in (`" + exiftoolLocation + " -s \"" + name1+docName[1]+'-2'+'.jpg' + "\"  ^| find /i \"a\"  ` ) do (.,.......)
```

launch a cmd window and immediatly close it.  without that part: "^| find /i \"a\"" tahe give a list of tags.

Comment: please elaborate what does not work exactly.
try replacing every separate command you are running with echo command, where is the first instance that did not run as you expected? (the `find`, the command in the `do`, the `exiftoolLocation`?)

Comment: "^| find /i \"a\"" make script fall.

Comment: Please tell us in what way it "does not work" ([edit] your question and clarify)!

Comment: launch a cmd window and immediatly close it.

Comment: without that part: "^| find /i \"a\"" tahe give a list of tags.

Comment: find is in C:\Windows\System32 location

Comment: I think you'll have better luck doing the for loop in javascript and just execute exiftool directly (one time, without the for loop). I don't have Photoshop so I cannot test and I don't really know the Photoshop runtime API but I can try write what I think should be the way to do it if you're OK with a not 100% tested answer

Comment: Yes, I am ok to test it.